# Correct usage of Castle Windsor 3.3 with Web Api 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, owin, castle-windsor

I am working on a big ASP.NET Web Api OData application which is using Dependency Inject with Castle Windsor and OWIN startup. Actually it only injects into each Controller an instance of Entity Framework but somehow we are getting some memory spike and the memory profiler shows that the problem is related to Entity Framework not disposed as expected.

I can see that the spike is in the call **.AsNoTracking()**.
I use it because MSDN mentions: "*Usage of NoTracking() is recommended when your query is meant for read operations.*"

The problem is in the memory usage in IIS, more calls are executed and more memory is hold by the Application Pool and it is never released. So after few queries the memory goes up to 1 GB without any logical reason.

So I'll share my code and look for suggestions, comments.

**WEB CONFIG**

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" 
  type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
</modules>
```

**OWIN STARTUP**

```
// HttpConfiguration config
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(new MyControllersInstaller());
container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(container));
config.DependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(container);
```

**WINDSOR DEPENDENCY RESOLVER**

```
public class WindsorDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    public WindsorDependencyResolver(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new WindsorDependencyScope(container);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return container.Kernel.HasComponent(serviceType) ? container.Resolve(serviceType) : null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return container.ResolveAll(serviceType).Cast<object>();
    }
}
```

**WINDSOR DEPENDENCY SCOPE**

```
public class WindsorDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
{
    public WindsorDependencyScope(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.scope = container.BeginScope();
    }

    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;
    private readonly IDisposable scope;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.scope.Dispose();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (container.Kernel.HasComponent(serviceType))
        {
            return container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.container.ResolveAll(serviceType).Cast<object>();
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLERS + EF INSTALLER**

```
public class MvcInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
   public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
   {
   container.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(typeof(MyController).Assembly)
      .BasedOn<ODataController>()
      .LifestylePerWebRequest());

   container.Register(
      Component
      .For<DbContext>()
      .ImplementedBy<MyEfContext>()
      .LifestylePerWebRequest());
   }
}
```

**ODATA CONTROLLER**

```
public class PersonsController : ODataController
{
    public PersonsController(DbContext session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    private readonly ICommandDispatcher commandDispatcher;
    private readonly DbContext session;


    public IQueryable<Person> Get()
    {
        return session
            .Set<Person>()
            .AsNoTracking();
    }

    public SingleResult<Person> Get([FromODataUri] Guid key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(session
            .Set<Person>()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Id == key));
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest that maybe this post will get more focused attention and better responses on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It looks to like it is about code review.

Comment: You are using "PerWebRequest" lifestyle. Do you have Windsor PerWebRequestLifestyleModule HTTP module configured in your web.config ? Without it, Windsor is not able to release components at the end of the request...

Comment: I do @MichalLevý but it looks like that on Azure it doesn't work. It works on Windows 2012 IIS 7 and 8 but in a web app of Azure it doesn't dispose anything. :-(

Comment: @Raffaeu Can you update your question with relevant part of web.config just to be sure ? But module registration is probably ok because you would get an exception from Castle otherwise